# Unique Merge multiple multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, grouping

I have some difficulties to merge many multidimensional array in php. I tried to do it by many way, but each time, I don't get the result wanted. I tried with array_merge(array_unique,...) and in different post I found a way with array_map, but I don't understand everything...

I can have many multi array like below:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    'User' => array(
        'username' => 'testje',
        'firstname' => 'jean',
        'lastname' => 'test'
    ),
    'Calendar' => array(
        'period' => 'AM'
    ),
    'Shift' => array(
        'name' => 'HV',
        'color' => '#b7fa00'
    ),
    'Team' => array(
        'name' => 'Proxy_B28'
    )
),
(int) 1 => array(
    'User' => array(
        'username' => 'testje',
        'firstname' => 'jean',
        'lastname' => 'test'
    ),
    'Calendar' => array(
        'period' => 'PM'
    ),
    'Shift' => array(
        'name' => 'HV',
        'color' => '#b7fa00'
    ),
    'Team' => array(
        'name' => 'Proxy_B28'
    )
)
)
```

And I would like to get this kind of array :

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'username' => 'testje',
        'firstname' => 'jean',
        'lastname' => 'test'
    ),
    'Calendar' => array(
        'period' => 'Full day'
    ),
    'Shift' => array(
        'name' => 'HV',
        'color' => '#b7fa00'
    ),
    'Team' => array(
        'name' => 'Proxy_B28'
    )
)
```

Do you have some advices to give me to get this result ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: i'm not clear with your question, what do you want in your final result?

Comment: The only difference I see is that `Calendar => 'AM'` and `Calendar => 'PM'` combine to `Calendar => 'Full day'` ?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I tried to get a unique array, because with the example above, the HTML line is duplicate in my table. As a user can be missing either on morning, or afternoon, or full day. if it's full fay, no needs to display it twice.

So I was wondering, if I can make a unique array from my controller and display unique value as the result shown. But I tried many way but each time I don't get the result expecting.

Thanks !

Comment: This is a poorly described problem statement.  The [mcve] is too minimal and cannot be used to distinguish good answers from bad answers.  We do not know which data points constitute a related data set.  I have voted to close as Unclear.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if the best solution but it seems to work like this, and fastly :

```
            foreach ($users as $k=>$v){             
            //$r[$k] = array_merge($v,$users[$k]);
            //$unique[] = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $users[$k])));

            $s[$k] = array(
                'username' => $v['User']['username'],
                'team'     => $v['Team']['name'],
                'period'   => $v['Calendar']['period']
            );

            if ($k > 0) {
                if (in_array($v['User']['username'],$s[$k])) {
                    unset($s[$k-1]);
                    $s[$k] = array(
                        'username' => $v['User']['username'],
                        'team'     => $v['Team']['name'],
                        'period'   => "FD"
                    );
                }   
            }


        }
```

Do you have another idea or this one is enough good ?
thank you !

Comment: I know the code it's not perfect...but do you have any advices to improve it ? Thank you